# How to link two Organizations with a pair relationship?

Tags: relationships

I have this situation I'm working on since way too long involving a sub type of Organization.

I work for a professional Union and 2 sub-organisations can belong to the same person. Which means that one contact owns 2 organizations or said differently two organizations share the same organization contact.

My first approach was to create an individual contact and an organization with a relationship of type owns/is owned by. Using the same individual contact, you could register dozens of organizations with this vertical link. The thing is that for my processes, all memberships acquired by the organization level were transferred to the individual and I couldn't have receipts for each particular organization with the specific contribution and the name of the owner (even with extended tokens)

So now, I changed my mind and focus on the relationship between organization. I've created a pair relationship and I'm wondering about how to link organizations between them. I thought about a CiviRule that would compare the custom fields created for the contact within the organization and add the relationship type (but haven't succeeded yet). I also thought about prepopulating custom fields from the URL sent after the first registration.

How would you deal with that?

(I'm working on Drupal 7.72 and CiviCRM 5.25 using a webform for the registration)

Answer (score 2):

Finally it works back to the first approach. The tipping point was to set the organization as first contact in the CiviCRM tab of the webform and then the individual contact and also change the relationship order with Organization being A and Individual being B.

Which means that I can now link two organizations or more through the same individual contact but keep everything related to the membership/contribution at the organization level and find every single needed token with related token extension.

it's a great relief.